# Include and code on same line in C

Tags: c, include

I want a code in one line only. I haven't found something usefull for the    moment.

Exemple, I have:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int function(){write(1,"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz\n",27);return(0);}
```

And I'm searching something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>;int function(){write(1,"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz\n",27);return(0);}
```

Comment: And I want a billion on my bank account. Sometimes you won't get what you want.

Comment: what's the problem with separating by new line ??

Comment: Sorry Olaf, I wasn't knowing this isn't possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.  The `#include` preprocessing directive must be followed by a newline.  It's part of the syntax (6.10.1 in the C standard http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

It's generally okay to omit headers from your one-liner, although even better to make the code compile without headers.  If someone is going to plug your one-liner into a compiler, they'll know enough to fix a missing header or two.

Answer (score 6):

Such code violates the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).  Per section 6.10, an `#include` preprocessor directive takes the form:

```
# include pp-tokens new-line
```

Note that the new line is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can if you change the compilation command to pipe the output of `tr` to `gcc` or `clang`:

```
#include <unistd.h> @ int function(){write(1,"abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz\n",27);return(0);}
```

Compile with:

```
cat myfile.c | tr @ '
' | clang -x c99 -c -o myfile.o -
```

Comment: Because your answer is based on **some example**, it is the right Answer also. Of course both above answers are OK too, but not that was the question. Strange isn't it ?:))

Comment: By the way, there is no reason to judge the OP if he comes with such a Question. We will never know the reason and why he need that :))

Comment: It's not working for me: I get an error, clang do not reconize c99. But thanks, I will try in this way